# Tomcat8 ClassNotFoundException BasicDataSourceFactory

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, connection-pooling, tomcat8

Okay so I have been trying to get this to work for too long now. I really need some input for my case. I have read a lot of different questions about this and tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to be working for me.

I am trying to set up a database pooling on my environment on AWS. The environment config is:
64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.6.1 running Tomcat 8 Java 8.

The problem I am running in to is I get this exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory]
```

My set up is like this:

First context.xml file that I have put inside the .war under WEB-INF/conf/context.xml, is this the correct location first of all?

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxTotal="20"
          maxIdle="10"
          maxWaitMillis="10000"
          username="username"
          password="password"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://database-url.example"/>
</Context>
```

Here I have tried to both supply the factory parameter with different values such as

```
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
```

I have also tried adding both the `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp` library, also in my .war under WEB-INF/lib/

The I have the web.xml in my .war under WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<web-app>
. . .
  <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Then in my code I am doing this

```
public class Database {

private static DataSource dataSource;

static {
    try {
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
    } catch(NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getPoolConnection() {
    try {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

The problem probably boils down to the library not existing on the correct place, I have read about that you need to add it to CATALINA_HOME/lib, is this not the same location as I have added the library? How can I otherwise add libraries to this folder on my AWS environment?

Is there any other changes I need to make or add another library?

What I notice is that even though I add libraries in my .war WEB-INF/lib folder and add the `factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"` or to somethling like `factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"` it is still not working. And even though I set the factory as `DataSourceFactory` I still get the same exception that the `BasicDataSourceFactory` can't be found.

I think I need some clear explanation on which files or libraries goes EXACTLY in which folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I think I have figured out a way to solve it. I don't know if this is the best way though, but it seems to be working pretty good for me.

What I did was to skip all about the xml files and did everything in java instead.

I removed the stuff in context.xml and web.xml regarding the resource.

Then I changed my Database class like this, using some default settings I found and some that I modified for my case:

```
public class Database {

private static DataSource dataSource;

static {
    // Getting environment variables I have set in server
    String dbName = System.getProperty("DB_NAME");
    String userName = System.getProperty("DB_USERNAME");
    String password = System.getProperty("DB_PASSWORD");
    String hostname = System.getProperty("DB_HOSTNAME");
    String port = "3306"; //System.getProperty("RDS_PORT");

    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + dbName);
    p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    p.setUsername(userName);
    p.setPassword(password);
    p.setJmxEnabled(true);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setValidationInterval(30000);
    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
    p.setMaxActive(20);
    p.setInitialSize(5);
    p.setMaxWait(15000);
    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
    p.setMaxIdle(10);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);
    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    p.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;" +
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
    dataSource = new DataSource();
    dataSource.setPoolProperties(p);
}

public static Connection getPoolConnection() {
    try {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

To read more about this solution, I found my answer over here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html under the section Code Example Plain Ol' Java